# c# winforms in the debugger.... context switch deadlock detected

Tags: c#, contextswitchdeadlock

So I'm running a unit test, it's a "bad" unit test which takes a *LONG* time to run. (which used to work just fine)

Now I'm getting the Context switch deadlock Detected error, I'm guessing because it's
such a long process (20 min) to do the whole test.

Much like described here:
http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/471705-context-switch-deadlock-detected

Is there anything I can do to get the unit test to run without the error?

If there is nothing else i can take it out of the tests and write a littel wrapper app, but
we only do these tests once or twice a year, and that seems like alot of work...

Thanks,

Cal-

Comment: It is a COM error.  This doesn't go anywhere unless you give us an idea what kind of COM component you are using.  Ultimately it is a debugger warning, no need to run unit tests from a debugger...

Comment: Thansks,
I'm hitting the Db and then doing a bunch of AD stuff to build our domain and populate the students. I'm not purposefully usig a com component but .Net may be doing so udner the hood to do the Ad stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans said, if you run the Unit tests that are running slow, instead of debuging them 
it works fine.

In our weird cheezy case that's fine.

Thanks,

E-